# receive specific data from Firebase with if statement in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am new with Firebase and React Native. I have created a database and now that when a certain number is equal to a number in 1 of the objects in firebase, it stores this data in an array.
I have the following code for that:

```
scanOutput = '0';

getUserData = () => {
    console.log(this.scanOutput);
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('Questions/1R1/NL');
    ref.on('value' , snapshot =>{
      var state = snapshot.val();

      console.log(state);

      if('1' === this.scanOutput){
        this.setState({questions: state});
      }
    })

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.scanOutput = this.props.navigation.getParam('output'); 
    this.getUserData();
  }
```

the database looks like this:

[image]

Currently the if statement contains a "1" hardcoded, what I want to achieve is that when this.scanOutput (in this case "1") equals "question_number" from the database, it places all data in the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is reading all data under `Questions/1R1/NL`. Since there may be multiple questions under there, the `snapshot` may contain multiple child nodes. Your callback needs to handle those by looping over `snapshot.forEach`.

Something like this:

```
  let ref = firebase.database().ref('Questions/1R1/NL');
  ref.on('value' , snapshot =>{
    snapshot.forEach((question) => {
      var state = question.val();

      if(state.question_number === this.scanOutput){
        this.setState({questions: state});
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! Unfortunately when I try the code I get the following error:
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near) '... questions.map ...') maybe you have an explanation for that?

Comment: Thanks the code works! I tried to read an object instead of an array. This code of yours is completely correct! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If `snapshot` returns you an object then you can destructure it:

```
const { question_number } = snapshot.val();
console.log(question_number);
```

then you can have a check like:

```
if(question_number === this.scanOutput){
```